# Rmarkdown: writing html with variables

Tags: r, r-markdown

How do I add HTML inside a code block in Rmarkdown in order to use variables in the HTML code?

For example, this works:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
#some R code
```
<div><img src='http://example.com/image.jpg'></div>
````

This doesn't work:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
my_image <- "image.jpg"
html(paste0("<div><img src='http://example.com/",my_image,"'></div> ") 
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tags` from `library(htmltools)`  (or `library(shiny)`)

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(htmltools)

my_image <- "http://example.com/myImage.jpg"
tags$div(tags$img(src = my_image))

```
````